# STM32F4 ADC DMA config not working

Tags: c, stm32, dma, adc

I'm trying to get ADC with DMA working on my STM32F411RE nucleo board. 
the signal is connected to the PC0 pin (ADC channel 10, DMA2), but whenever I check, the uhADC1ConvertedValue is 0. Am I missing something? Is my config wrong?

```
__IO uint32_t uhADC1ConvertedValue;

unsigned int getADCVal(){
    return uhADC1ConvertedValue;
}


void ADC2_Init(){
    ADC_InitTypeDef       ADC_InitStructure;
    ADC_CommonInitTypeDef ADC_CommonInitStructure;
    DMA_InitTypeDef       DMA_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef      GPIO_InitStructure;

    uhADC1ConvertedValue = 1;

    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1, ENABLE);

    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_0;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)&ADC1->DR;;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t)&uhADC1ConvertedValue;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralToMemory;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 1;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Disable;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Disable;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFOThreshold_HalfFull;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBurst = DMA_MemoryBurst_Single;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBurst = DMA_PeripheralBurst_Single;
    DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream0, &DMA_InitStructure);
    DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream0, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL ;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_Mode = ADC_Mode_Independent;
    ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_Prescaler = ADC_Prescaler_Div2;
    ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_DMAAccessMode = ADC_DMAAccessMode_Disabled;
    ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_TwoSamplingDelay = ADC_TwoSamplingDelay_5Cycles;
    ADC_CommonInit(&ADC_CommonInitStructure);

    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_12b;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge_None;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T1_CC1;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_NbrOfConversion = 1;
    ADC_Init(ADC1, &ADC_InitStructure);

    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_Channel_10, 1, ADC_SampleTime_3Cycles);

    ADC_DMARequestAfterLastTransferCmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

    ADC_DMACmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

    ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

    ADC_EOCOnEachRegularChannelCmd(ADC1, ENABLE);


}


int main(void)
{
    int rev = 0;

    uC_Init();


    rev = getADCVal(); //enc28j60getrev();

    simple_server();

    return rev;
}
```

Comment: 1) If you read an `uint32_t` you should return an `uint32_t`. Then you assign the `unsigned` result to a signed `int`. Do not change signed-ness unless you have good reason. If you have, change it at the lowest possible abstraction level once. 2) Why do you qualify a normal variable `__IO`? If you mean `volatile`, use it! 3) Do not use that bloatware STlib. It is no way standard, but just obfuscates and slows down your code.

Comment: Hi - i fixed what you suggested, but sadly to no avail - still no reading. At the moment I have to use the STPlib.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really tell what was wrong with my previous code (probably the part where i didn't start the timer that would start the ADC), but here is a working one (this code keeps ADC doing conversions continously (well, started by a timer) and loads the measured value into a variable):

```
volatile uint32_t uhADC1ConvertedValue;

uint32_t getADCVal(){
    return uhADC1ConvertedValue;
}
void adc_init(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef      GPIO_InitStructure;

    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL ;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_ADC1EN;
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA2EN;

    //konfiguracja ADC
    ADC1->CR2 = ADC_CR2_ADON |                          //włącz ADC
                ADC_CR2_EXTEN_0 |                       //wyzwalanie przetwornika zboczem opadającym i narastającym
                ADC_CR2_EXTSEL_3 | ADC_CR2_EXTSEL_0 |   //wyzwalanie przetwornika kanałem 4 timera 4
                ADC_CR2_DDS |                           //kontynuuj przesył DMA po ostatnim przesyle (konieczne dla circular mode)
                ADC_CR2_DMA;                            //włącz DMA dla ADC

    //włączenie skanowania i przerwania dla zakonczonej konwersji
    ADC1->CR1 = ADC_CR1_SCAN; //| ADC_CR1_EOCIE;

    //Ustawienie czasu konwersji na 3 + 12 cykli zegara ADC, zegar ADC == 42MHz częstotliwosć próbkowania ~1Ms
    ADC1->SMPR1 = 0;//ADC_SMPR1_SMP11_1 | ADC_SMPR1_SMP12_1;

    //Ustawienie ilosci kanałów do skanowania
    ADC1->SQR1 = (1)<<20;

    //Ustawienie kanałów 11 i 12 do skanowania
    ADC1->SQR3 = 10<<5;

    //Konfiguracja DMA dla przetwornika ADC1
    DMA2_Stream0->NDTR = 1;                 //ilosc bajtów do przesłania
    DMA2_Stream0->PAR = (uint32_t)&ADC1->DR;
    DMA2_Stream0->M0AR = (uint32_t)&uhADC1ConvertedValue;

    DMA2_Stream0->CR =  DMA_SxCR_PL_1 |     //priority high
                        DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_0 |  //memory size 16bit
                        DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_0 |  //pheriperial size 16bit
                        DMA_SxCR_MINC |     //inkrementuj wskaźnik po stronie pamięci
                        DMA_SxCR_CIRC |     //zapętlenie bufora pamięci
                        DMA_SxCR_EN;        //włączenie kontrolera DMA

    //konfiguracja timera dla przetwornika
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM4EN;
    TIM4->CR1 = 0;                          //resetowanie rejestru konfiguracji
    TIM4->PSC = 0;                          //prescaller na 0
    TIM4->ARR = 167;                        //reload register na 83
    TIM4->CCR4 = 167;                       //rejesrt compare dla wyzwalania przetwornika
    TIM4->CCMR2 |= TIM_CCMR2_OC4M_0 | TIM_CCMR2_OC4M_1; //przełączanie wyjcia przy compare
    TIM4->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC4E;            //włączenie wyjcia 4

    //konfiguracja NVIC
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);               //przerwanie od zakonczenia konwersji ADC

    //uruchom przetwornik
    ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_ADON;

    //uruchom timer
    TIM4->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN;


}



int main(void)
{
    uint32_t rev;
    int bb= 0;
    uC_Init();
    //ADC2_Init();
    adc_init();
    rev = uhADC1ConvertedValue;
    rev = uhADC1ConvertedValue;
    rev = uhADC1ConvertedValue;
    for (bb=0; bb< 100000; bb++) // tu dociera i sie wywala
        {;;}

    rev = uhADC1ConvertedValue;
    rev = uhADC1ConvertedValue;
    rev = uhADC1ConvertedValue;
    rev = uhADC1ConvertedValue;

//  rev = 20;

    /**/
    simple_server(); //petla nieskonczona

    return rev;
}
```

Comment: I found this post while having DMA config issues. Perhaps your DMA clock is not enabled?  My issue turned out to be a bug in CubeMX https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000Bmob3uSQA/dma-not-working-in-cubemx-generated-code-order-of-initialization